# How to discuss the results of this meta-analysis?

Tags: statistical-significance, proportion, meta-analysis, reporting

I recently performed a meta-analysis where I was basically looking to find the proportion of people with disease X in people with disease Y. I did not find a significant value, it was solely the proportion (also significant heterogeneity was found). I am wondering, how would I discuss these results in the discussion section? If I am just given a proportion, how do I discuss the implications if I did not find any significance value?
By the way, I did not make up the research question. It’s not like I am confused about my own question.

Comment: You may know what you are asking but your post does include more than one question.  You can find valuable information about meta analysis in the book and other works of Larry Hedges and Ingram Olkin. In your case Simpson's paradox may be in effect.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in assuming that statistical significance is not an issue here. You can report the proportion you found with its confidence interval and leave it at that. If you had had people with the disease in two groups you could have compared them which people who like statistical significance would have computed a p-value from but that does not seem to be what you had.